# Grid view sorting

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i am using this code for sorting in grid view but this is not working. please help

```
 <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="FirstName">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Name
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("Name")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Have you done something in your code?

Comment: this is not showing link  in header to sort as i am using sort expression

Comment: yea i have fired sorting event and write code in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you don't see link at the table's header.

It might help you,

Make sure that you set the `AllowSorting="true"` and created a event to handle it `OnSorting="gvActivities_Sorting"`

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvActivities" AllowSorting="true" 
 OnSorting="gvActivities_Sorting">
```

If you did it you should get a link in the header.

If not post the all gridview decleration